# Не всегда срабатывает register_next_step_handler

Tags: python, telebot

Есть бот на `pyTelegramBotApi`

```py
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot('123:abc')

bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay=0.5)
bot.load_next_step_handlers()

...
```

Не всегда срабатывает `bot.register_next_step_handler`

Иногда все нормально, бот сразу отвечает, иногда только через несколько сообщений.

Как быть, в чем проблема?

Comment: вы описываете проблему с функцией bot.register_next_step_handler, но не используете ее в коде? Представьте пример кода где возникают ошибки.

Comment: Присоединюсь к вопросу. Также не всегда срабатывает, уже замучался дебажить:(

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вызвать функцию вместо использования:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler
```

Например, вы пишете:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(message, название_функции)
```

а нужно написать:

```
название_функции(message)
```